# Fill cells based on the values of existing cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of lines. For Example:

> A1=E, A2=E, A3=S, A4=E, A5=S, A6=C, A7=C, A8=E

I am looking for a formula that I can drag down and based on the sequence it can determine the category. For example if E then E only, if E followed by S then result shows as "E + S", if E followed by S and C or multiple Cs then "FM" to indicate family.

Comment: Jolie. Please provide more detail and a better example. Your question is difficult to understand and it's unlikely that someone will be able to help you unless they understand the precise problem.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you would need to write a makro for that purpose. There is a makro editor integrated in Excel ("ALT-F11"). 
Makros can be associated to keyboard shortcuts. So you could mark a sequence and hit the shortcut and then the makro can determine the category ad put it e.g. into a different column.